# How to automatically navigate to login page in the Spring MVC app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-security

I have a Spring MVC app where user must be redirected to the login page when session is expired. I tried common solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195795/spring-mvc-redirect-user-to-login-page-once-session-is-expired). But it does not redirect **automatically**, it redirects when user clicks any link or takes some action.

Then I created this class

```
@Component
public class SessionEndedListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent> {

    protected static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(SessionEndedListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent event)
    {
        log.info("Session expired or have been destroyed!");
    }

}
```

And now, my `onApplicationEvent` is fired when session expires. However, I can't redirect from this method.

How to redirect **automatically** when session is expired?
My Spring version is 4.2.5 and Spring Security version is 4.1.4.

Comment: There is no connection between your UI and your backend all the time. So in general, HTTP is request-response, you send a request and get the response and that's it. Use websocket for instance to create  full-duplex communication. The behavior you have now is correct - you should be redirected when you make some action (request to the server) and server will redirect if session has expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how http work, basically you are not able to do this because there is not long living connection between server and client when you are in a web site/app, so basically the only time server can tell your session have expired is when you perform an action and communicate with it.

Said that there are some commons alternatives you try for example add javascript client code (that is executed in your browser for example each 5/10 seconds) and ping server to identify if session have been expired.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solved my problem with JavaScript pinging to the backend as you suggested.